# Cannot capture amounts after DoExpressCheckoutPayment with parallel payment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I user PayPal's Express Checkout API to make an parallel Payment. Everything works fine, on the payee site, the 2 payments are booked as "open".

While DoExpressCheckoutPayment I get an transaction id for each payment. But a doCapture fails with "You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call". A single authorized payment that I made several weeks ago but have never captured gives me just "Order%20has%20expired%2e" - which is fine.

I use the following parameters for the NVP API:

```
    $parameters = array("METHOD"=>"DoCapture",
                "AUTHORIZATIONID"=>$transactionid_item,
                "AMT"=>$amt_item,
                "CURRENCYCODE"=>$currencycode,
                "COMPLETETYPE"=>"Complete"
               );
```

when of course the variable are the corresponding values to each payment. (plus authentication/api credential).

What am I doing wrong? Is there an additional variable to set when I make a parallel instead of an single payment?

regards,

chris

This is an example call and the response:

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=DoCapture&AUTHORIZATIONID=O-67121848EA448750G&AMT=9.70&CURRENCYCODE=EUR&COMPLETETYPE=Complete&USER=xxx&PWD=xxx&SIGNATURE=xxx&VERSION=95.0

array(9) {
  ["TIMESTAMP"]=>
  string(28) "2013%2d06%2d15T09%3a35%3a52Z"
  ["CORRELATIONID"]=>
  string(12) "140dec053198"
  ["ACK"]=>
  string(7) "Failure"
  ["VERSION"]=>
  string(6) "95%2e0"
  ["BUILD"]=>
  string(7) "6444009"
  ["L_ERRORCODE0"]=>
  string(5) "10007"
  ["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]=>
  string(19) "Permission%20denied"
  ["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]=>
  string(67) "You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call"
  ["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]=>
  string(5) "Error"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the API request that you are sending minus your credentials and the API response you are getting back.  Using the Correlation ID that is returned in the response, I can check our logs on this side to see what the issue may be.

Comment: Okay, I've addeded it to the original post. Maybe I'm simply doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running your Express Checkout API call as an order, then you are turning around and doing a DoCapture request but you are passing over the order id for the auth id instead of the authorization id.  If you are wanting to set your Express Checkout to be an order instead of an auth or a sale, then you need to perform the calls in the following ways.

SetExpressCheckout API call (processing as order)
GetExpressCheckoutDetail API Call
DoExpressCheckoutPayment API Call (processing as order)

DoAuthorization (performs an auth, and passes over the order id that you received from the EC flow)

DoCapture (performs a capture against the auth, you will pass over the auth id that was returned in the previous call here, not the order id)

Comment: Hi, this is all done by processing as order. The thing I did not know was, that I have to make DoAuthorization before DoCapture. So I tried but had not luck. So for this I did .../nvp?METHOD=DoAuthorization&TRANSACTIONID=O-66439431R6885290D&AMT=9.70&TRANSACTIONENTITY=Order&CURRENCYCODE=EUR&USER=...&PWD=...&SIGNATURE=...&VERSION=95.0 but got an Permission%20denied back. What is now wrong?

Comment: This is an old question, but just for the sake of anyone who comes across it later: the above answer makes it sound like DoAuthorization is a required step. It is not. You can do DoEC (order), DoAuth(from the order), DoCapture(from the auth), OR you can do DoEC(order), DoCapture(from the order), without the intervening DoAuth call. The caller's error was just that they were saying they had an authID when they actually were passing an orderID. You have to identify which ID you have correctly. Also note that DoCapture against an OrderID is NOT guaranteed to succeed since funds were not reserved.