# Authorize & process payment after 1 day when token expires within 3 hours

Tags: php, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using the paypal classic API to authorize and process a payment using Express Checkout (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/).

Although the authorization is valid for three days according to the documentation, the token expires within three hours.

So, how can I capture the transaction after the token has expired?

PS.
I'm aware this is a duplicate of [How am I supposed to capture a payment 1 day after its authorization if the PayPal token expires after 3 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240419/how-am-i-supposed-to-capture-a-payment-1-day-after-its-authorization-if-the-payp/17242864#17242864) but like the questioning user, the 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment' could be done after the three hour period.

Answer (score 0):

Both the poster of the referenced question and you are making the same mistake in understanding the PayPal concepts.

A token and an authorization are not the same thing at all. A token is a mechanism to connect a user agreement to an upcoming financial transaction; think of it as an extension to or part of a web session. A token describes an in-process action, and can be used to generate a financial transaction, but IS NOT a financial transaction itself.

An authorization is one type of financial transaction that could be generated from that token/session. An authorization reserves funds from a buyer, thus giving the seller/receiver a guarantee that funds will be available from the buyer for a certain period of time. It does not actually move funds; that only happens when (if) a second financial transaction is executed in reference to the authorization: a "capture." In short, an authorization & capture split a "sale" into two pieces: one that ensures the transaction *can* occur, and a second that actually makes it happen.

You should be executing DoExpressCheckout with paymentaction of "authorization" as soon as the user returns (well, perhaps after another page or two on your site... but not days later). Then you throw away the EC token and just keep the authorization #. The only action that you should be performing days later should be a capture, which only requires that authorization #.

I'm guessing that fulfilling the customer's order in some fashion, either digitally or physically, is the cause of the delay before you capture.

If you want to avoid holding funds in the customer's account, and are willing to accept some risk that the funds will therefore not be present when you go to capture, you could also use paymentaction of 'order' to do what amounts to a non-binding authorization at the time of the buyer's interaction.

If you have a more complex situation, e.g. the amount is not known at the time of the user's interaction session, then rather than using an authorization you need to use a different PayPal product such as reference transactions/billing agreements/future payments that permit the user to grant you a more open-ended permission to bill them in the futur.

Comment: thanks! I'm doing a DoExpressCheckoutpayment passing the payerID, the token & authorization as paymentAction. But then the transaction is being completed (namely the money is being transferred as seen in my sandbox). I could save the TransactionID and do a CAPTURE later, but any clue how to not make the transaction?

Comment: If you have paymentaction=authorization, money will NOT be transferred. The buyer account will show a transaction of type "authorization" which claims the money (although the funds would be released if the authorization is cancelled or left to expire), but the receiving account will have no money come into it's balance until there is a capture. If you are seeing money movement then you have NOT done only an authorization.

Answer (score 0):

solved this (kind of) thanks to @geewiz.

1) I am doing a parallel payment to with "paymentaction = order" to two stores.

2) After the user accepts the parallel payment, I get a token with which I do a DoExpressCheckoutPayment to both paypal stores. paymentaction remains order.

3) I then get a link with which I do a DoCapture, which releases the money and transfers it to my account.

**SECONDARY QUESTION -**

how can the second store owner (since I have a parallel payment) capture his share of the payment?

Calling the same function with his transaction ID throws a "*You do not have permissions to make this API call*" error, since the signature of the php script is of my store.

Comment: Your followup question is confusing. Express Checkout does not support parallel or chained payments. Are you trying to use Adaptive Payments features? You will probably get better help if you create a new question, giving more background.

Comment: I'm basically trying to authorize a parallel (or chained) payment to two accounts, which can be captured at a later point (within 24 hours). I'll take a look at adaptive payments. I have exactly the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112570/cannot-capture-amounts-after-doexpresscheckoutpayment-with-parallel-payment (also not solved)

Comment: That other author was having two problems; the first was diagnosed & fixed, which was that he was passing an order_id and calling it an authorization_id. The second was never diagnosed, but the "you do not have permission to make this call" error almost always means that invalid or inappropriate authentication (account/password/key) was passed; e.g. they were trying to use sandbox credentials on live, or were passing the credentials of an account that was not the appropriate party to the transaction (e.g. the sending account cannot call capture API, only the receiving account).

Answer (score 0):

solved by:

1) SetExpressCheckout to own account (payment action == order)

```
$request_params = array(

    'RETURNURL' => $obj['SUCCESSURL'],
    'CANCELURL' => $obj['CANCELURL'],
    'NOSHIPPING' => '1',
    'BRANDNAME' => $obj['BRANDNAME'],

    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => $obj['CURRENCY'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC' => $obj['ITEMDESCRIPTION'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Order',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $obj['AMOUNTTOTAL'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => $obj['RECEIVER1'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID' => $obj['REQUESTID1']

);

$response = $obj['PAYPAL']->request('SetExpressCheckout', $request_params);
```

2) DoExpressCheckout

```
$request_params = array(
    'TOKEN' => $obj['TOKEN'],
//  'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Authorization',
    'PAYERID' => $obj['PAYERID'],

    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Order',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $obj['AMOUNTTOTAL'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => $obj['RECEIVER1'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID' => $obj['REQUESTID1'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => $obj['CURRENCY']
);

$response = $obj['PAYPAL']->request('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $request_params);
echo '<b>02. DO TRANSACTION</b><br />';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

3) DoCapture within 24 hours to own account

```
echo '<a href="pay_app.php?tid=' . $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID'] . '&amt='. $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT'] . '">CAPTURE AS APP</a><br/>';
```

4) on success of DoCapture do MassPayment to second account

```
$request_params = array(

    'L_EMAIL0' => $obj['RECEIVERHOST'],
    'L_AMT0' => $obj['AMT'],
    'L_NOTE0' => "transaction complete",
    'CURRENCYCODE' => $obj['CURRENCY']
);

$response = $obj['PAYPAL']->request('MassPay', $request_params);

echo '<b> MASSPAY</b><br />';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '<br/>';
print_r($obj);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br/>';
```

Comment: Yes, this is a working and sensible pattern anda  good way to make "derivative" or "chained" payments, e.g. to participating sellers or content providers in a network.